# memory allocation about python

Tags: python, memory-management

I run the following python code.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,l=[]):
        self.k = l
    a = A()
    b = A()
    a.k.append(5)
    print id(a.k) == id(b.k)
    print b.k
```

The result is:

```
True
[5]
```

I don't know *why* a.k and b.k have the same memory address.

Comment: Removed totally superfluous `k = 1` and reformatted it to look nicer but mostly so it would compile :-) And, please, for the love of whatever god(s) you believe in, consider moving to Python3 - it's *so* much better.

Answer (score 2):

Because that empty list you're assigning to `l` is created *once* when the function is *[defined](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values),* not each time the function is called.

Hence `l` for both classes will point to the same list and therefore changing one will change the other (or, more correctly, changing one will change the *only one*).

If you want to ensure each object of the class gets its *own* list, simply use the slicing method:

```
self.k = l[:]
```